# Math equations not rendering in docusaurus

Tags: docusaurus, katex

Following instructions exactly as they are on:
https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/math-equations

Also checked that katex.css was properly loaded.

But equations not rendering. Below are the relevant parts of my docusaurus.config.js script. Will appreciate

```
// enable kateX for math
const math  = require('remark-math');
const katex = require('rehype-katex');

/** @type {import('@docusaurus/types').Config} */
/** @type {import('@docusaurus/types').Config} */
const config = {
  
  presets: [
    [
      'classic',
      /** @type {import('@docusaurus/preset-classic').Options} */
      ({
        docs: {
          remarkPlugins: [math,{strict:false}],
          rehypePlugins: [[katex, {strict: false}]],

          
      }),
    ],
  ],

  stylesheets: [
    {
      href: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.13.24/dist/katex.min.css',
      type: 'text/css',
      integrity:
        'sha384-odtC+0UGzzFL/6PNoE8rX/SPcQDXBJ+uRepguP4QkPCm2LBxH3FA3y+fKSiJ+AmM',
      crossorigin: 'anonymous',
    },
  ],

  
};
```

Followed instructions on https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/4017

Comment: I use `remarkPlugins: [math], rehypePlugins: [katex], ` and it works...